# Pig not working in terminal

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I am new to pig and i have downloaded from

http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror/pig/pig-0.10.1/
 Now when i write pig in my linux terminal it displays the following message

```
2013-04-26 17:14:53,641 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/vishal/Downloads/pig_1366976693634.log
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:587)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 7 mor
```

Is it that i have to include jar or what else can be the issue

Thanks

Comment: try `pig -x local`, the default mode is mapreduce, you need to install hadoop for that. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/start.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the mapred java archive, depending on which MapReduce version you use, MRv1 or MRv2 (=YARN).

FYI: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is always about a forgotten/mistyped JAR-file